# Can I use only one concept or I need to use the inheritance in java?

Tags: java, uml

I have a doubt concerning my conception and I would like to ask your advice

I have a table schedule in my database:

[image]

The special schedule is defined by a date and the normal schedule by a dayName.

I would like to know when I create my concept for the class diagram i need to to use a inheritance like this ?

[image]

Or i can create only a concept with date and dayName together and if is special schedule dayName will be null and if normal schedule date will be null?

[image]

Thank you very much for the advices.

Comment: Please do **not** link to screenshots. Especially when the *information* in that picture could very well be expressed using formatted text.

Comment: It would help if your screenshots would all use the same naming (language). I think it is personal preference what you want to use. If you go with only 1 class, then some methods should be available that tell you if its a `normal schedule` or a `special schedule` as you will probably need an easy way to distinguish both. My preference would be to use 1 class only, as you only have 1 field which would be different. Once you get a few more fields which are not common, then you can start to think about a super class which will be extended

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

Either is OK. Do what is better for you.

### Do what suits you best

Whether you look at the programming principles, database building or concept modelling the main thing is you are not limited or bound by any specific rules - these are just guidelines that you may follow or ignore. The main rule is to do what suits you best. For instance neither UML nor Java (or any other programming language) enforces you to use inheritance here. If you should use it or not will heavily depend on how different are the two types of schedule. If they offer different operations or operation realisation, associations etc. it might be better to handle them as two inheriting classes rather than just one class but if it is just a property, go on with a single class and add a constraint that only one of those two attributes is not null at the same time. Note also that the same concept might pose an inheriting classes when modelling a code but a single entity when defining the database structure.

### About the notation

It's a side note to your question. You misuse the generalization. In UML the generalization arrow goes from the more specific to the more generic class. It also does not have any additional inscriptions (like the *Extends*) - the arrow shape itself is reserved for generalization purpose only. On the other hand Extends is a restricted keyword used for dependencies between use cases. So reverse your arrows and remove the Extends from the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

> "*Keep it simple, Stupid!*"

means that write your code always simple. If you have complex concepts you can use inheritance. But only this model i advice to you just change your model.

Comment: Furthermore: multiple inheritance is a concept from hell.

Comment: @ThomasKilian tell that to Bjarne Stroustrup ;-) But the reality here is that it is not a multi-inheritance, just inverted arrows.

Comment: @Ister Uhm, "inverted arrows"? What does that mean?

Comment: OP draw them in incorrect direction. Obviously normalSchedule and specialSchedule are both specialisations of schedule